# Consider this relation on the set $A = \{1, 2, 3, . . . 50 \} $with n = 5. Write the set [1] explicitly

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Recall that when $n$ is a positive integer, we say that integers $x$ and $y$ are
congruent modulo n, and write $x \equiv y\pmod n$, provided $n\mid(x-y)$

Consider this relation on the set $B= \{1, 2, 3, . . . 50\}$ with $n= 5$. Write the
set [1] explicitly

Would the set be everything where $x$ is $5$ and $y$ is a multiple of $5$?

$= {(5,5),(5,10),(5,15),(5,20),(5,25),(5,30),(5,35),(5,40),(5,45),(5,50)} $?

Comment: You have not explicitly defined $[1]$.  In the absence of that information, I suspect it refers to those numbers in $B$ with remainder $1$ when divided by $5$.

Comment: I believe the square brackets indicate the “equivalence class of” 1.  If that’s true, do you know which numbers in $B$ are equivalent to 1?

Comment: @Joe@N. F. Taussig  My apologies, it also specifies (writing out all the elements between braces) at the end, which is referring to [1] I think?                                                          Consider this relation on the set **B= {1, 2, 3, . . . 50}** with **n = 5**. Write the
set [1] explicitly (writing out all the elements between braces)

Comment: @Joe would the numbers in _B_ equivalent 1 be y where 5 | (5 - y) is true? So 5, 10, 15, 20....50?

Comment: No, two numbers are equivalent mod 5 if their difference is divisible by 5.  If the notation $[1]$ means the equivalence class of 1, like I think, then you are looking for the numbers equivalent to 1, mod 5.

Comment: @Joe 1, mod 5 as in   x ≡ 1 (mod 5) where x is the numbers I'm looking for and 1 is y? So, the elements 6, 11, 16, 21, 26....46?

Comment: Yes, correct. Again, assuming your notation means what I think, of which I’d say I’m 95% confident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the numbers in $\{1,\dots,50\}$ congruent to $1 \pmod 5$.  They are $[1]=\{1,6,11,16,\dots,46\}$.

Comment: Thanks, I had just figured it out but totally forgot the **1** since **0** is a multiple of anything. If I was to expand set **B** to be the set **Z** (all integers) instead, would  writing it in set builder notation  be **Z = {x : x ∈ Z, x = 5 | (x-1) }?**

Comment: I would write $[1]=\{1+5k: k\in \Bbb Z\}$.  This is $\{x: 5\mid x-1\}$.  Your set builder notation is off because of the $"x="$.  Take that out.